# How to drag / re-center the displayed Tableau worksheet?

Tags: tableau-api

Suppose I wish to focus on the state of Colorado in the following chloropeth map:

[image]

The typical mechanism is to use the operating-system dependent means of dragging the picture. I am on OS/X so that involves using two fingers to drag the image to the desired new centering location.

However the *actual* result of that operation is a **bounding box** is displayed on the image (I can not get a screenshot of it since it disappears)

So then .. how to drag /re-center the Tableau display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click onto the small 'play' arrow button on the chart menu in the top left hand corner. A sub menu will pop up where you can select the scroll method you'd like - click and drag is one of these. You can also disable this through the chart options (the small drop down menu on the top right hand corner of the chart).